# Flask send_from_directory requests an environ positional argument

Tags: flask

You might be serving files to users at some point using Flask's standard `send_from_directory`, e.g.:

```
return send_from_directory(directory=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'files'), path=filename)
```

but you keep getting

````
TypeError: send_from_directory() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environ'```
````

Comment: Got mad trying to solve this bug, turns out to be a wrong import. Posted here in case anyone else has the same problem at some point (usually due to "smart" imports by your code editor)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not using Flask's `send_from_directory()` but the underlying `werkzeug` one.

Change your imports from

`from werkzeug.utils import send_from_directory`

to

`from flask import send_from_directory`